# Simple Compute Pay Function

Tags: python

Can this be made any simpler/shorter/more efficient?

This function will compute paycheck amount according to hours worked and rate per hour.

```
def compute_pay(hours: int, rate: float) -> float:
    """Computes pay according to hours worked and rate per hours.

    For every hour worked after the 40th hour the rate per hour
    is multipled by 1.5
    """

    pay = 0

    if hours > 40:
        pay += 40 * rate
        hours -= 40
        pay += hours * rate * 1.5
    else:
        pay = hours * rate

    return pay


hrs = int(input('Hours: '))
hrs_rate = float(input('Rate: '))

print('Pay:', compute_pay(hrs, hrs_rate))
```

This is my second take on the above function:

```
def compute_pay(hours: int, rate: float) -> float:
    """Computes pay according to hours worked and rate per hours.

    For every hour worked after the 40th hour the rate per hour
    is multipled by 1.5
    """

    hours -= 40

    if hours > 0:
        pay = 40 * rate + (hours * rate * 1.5)
    else:
        pay = (hours + 40) * rate

    return pay


hrs = int(input('Hours: '))
hrs_rate = float(input('Rate: '))

print('Pay:', compute_pay(hrs, hrs_rate))
```

My aim is to have begginers' friendly logic while introducing Python features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review. I think the simpler way of expressing your code would look like this:

```
def compute_pay(hours: int, rate: float) -> float:
    return (min(hours, 40) + (max(0, hours - 40) * 1.5)) * rate

hrs = int(input('Hours: '))
hrs_rate = float(input('Rate: '))

print('Pay:', compute_pay(hrs, hrs_rate))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def compute_pay(hours: int, rate: float) -> float:
    return (hours + max(0, hours-40)/2) * rate
```

EDIT:
All `hours` must be multiplied with `rate` i.e. `hours*rate`. If `hours` is more than 40, then we need these extra hours to be multiplied with 1.5.

How much extra pay do we need to add to `hours*rate` to get correct pay? That would be

```
  max(0,hours-40)*1.5*rate - max(0,hours-40)*rate # Why subtract? Think! 
= max(0,hours-40)*0.5*rate
```

Therefore, `pay = hours*rate + max(0,hours-40)*0.5*rate`

Comment: Did you mean `(hours + max(0, hours-40)*2) * rate` ?